How to copy excel cell content to a string with vba
I want to save an Excel sheet as a file using vba code. That I have achieved.
    Sheets("html").Select
      
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Path = "C:\BridgeResultsTranslator\session date.html"
   
         FileNumber = FreeFile
   Open Path For Output As FileNumber
        For k = 1 To 1770
    Print #FileNumber, Cells(k, 1)
       Next k
   Close FileNumber

Tomorrow the sheet information will change and I want to save it as a file with a different name i.e. the date which will be stored in a specified cell.
To test successful code I changed the above to;
    Sheets("html").Select
      
  'rem xx = the contents of a cell (A18) containing a date

    Dim xx As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Path = "C:\BridgeResultsTranslator\test "

    xx = cell(A18)

    Path = Path + xx + ".html"
         FileNumber = FreeFile
   Open Path For Output As FileNumber
        For k = 1 To 1770
    Print #FileNumber, Cells(k, 1)
       Next k
   Close FileNumber

This of course does not work. I am sure there is simple code to copy text from a cell into the string xx but I am not finding it. Any help?

xx = Worksheets("html").Range("A18").value

'This works
'''
   Sheets("html").Select
'rem str = the contents of a cell A18 containg a date reference
   Dim str
   Dim Path As String
   Dim FileNumber As Integer
   Dim k As Integer
   Path = "C:\BridgeResultsTranslator\Session "
   str = (Range("A18"))
   Path = Path + str + ".html"
       FileNumber = FreeFile
   Open Path For Output As FileNumber
      For k = 1 To 1770
   Print #FileNumber, Cells(k, 1)
   Next k
   Close FileNumber

'''

Please edit your answer to enclose the code block in tripple backtics for better readability. Single code lines can be formatted by single backtics

Thank you, I didn't know I could edit or why it had displayed like that.
